# When I run the compiled exe file from File Explorer, when there is not DLL found it does not throw me DLL not found exception.Why

Tags: c#

I compiled the C# Application exe file using Visual Studio 2019. When I run the exe file where exe and dll files are in different location, I do not get Unhandled Exception Dialog. Why?

Comment: Is it a custom Dll or a system one? Is the Dll also in the Global Assembly Cache? There are a couple of other possible reasons as well. Won't know which one applies until we know about lots of different things in the project and its configuration

Comment: Its a custom dll

Comment: Is the custom DLL actually referenced by any code?

Comment: Actually in custom dll there is a class which I’ve inherited in my WinForms App.

Comment: Are these dlls already provided by .net Framework? Maybe they're located in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and you see in bin folder because in the reference the "copy local" flag setted on true, but always reachable by GAC when the exe is moved

Comment: These are the dlls made by me.

Comment: @AsrarSunge has the compiled code instructions that requires the missing DLL executed at runtime? Maybe if not the compiler knows that althought you declare DLL namespaces in your cs files, and you add the reference on project, you don't use them and so it cuts away a useless reference

Comment: @Sycraw i did not get your point.

Comment: @AsrarSunge if I have a dll with sum() method, I add the reference to a project (call it project A)... but I don't use the sum() method in project A, when I compile project A the compiler can understand that project A doesn't use the DLL, so it cuts away that reference from the project A.exe that is going to generate

Comment: I’m already using references

Comment: @Sycraw I Added the reference of dll to my project

Comment: @AsrarSunge What I'm saying is that if you add the reference to your project but on your code you don't use any instruction of that DLL, the compiler  probably will build an exe without that reference, because the compiler could consider that reference useless

Comment: How to add instructions of dll?